# How to implement if condition in jbehave

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

I have to implement scenario in jbehave like

---Perform some action
--- if parameter value is true then
      perform some more actions
----else
      complete scenarios; break

How can i implement this in jbehave?

Comment: I have tried implementing if else condition in java function itself but i dont want to do that way.  is there any wave to handle this kind of scenario in story file?

Comment: @PratikZinzuvadiya The reason there's no way to handle this inside a story file is because you're looking at two different contexts. Something happened to set that param value to true, or not, and if you want different behaviour in each case then each case is a different scenario.

Comment: Yes i understand that both are two different scenarios. So I guess we should write two different scenarios rather than implementing them as single scenario and using variable to switch the behavior, right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is not currently possible in JBehave.

The best solution would be just 2 different scenarios with different tags (e.g. environment parameters specification like @Setup incomplete and @Setup complete to split them) 
And after that you choose what to run basic on your knowledge about system state.

I have such an issue and workaround it that way. May be somebody has better decision.